# Refresh table content in django template on updation of mysqlDatabase content

Tags: ajax, django, django-models, django-templates

I am new to django and Ajax .I am able to fetch the database content from mysql database,now I want everytime the data is updated in database ,my table also should get updated.I know I have to  ajax ,but I dont have anyidea how to proceed with it.Please help me How I can proceed with it?
This is my **Views.py**

```
def index(request):
testBenchdb = TestBenchDB.objects.all()
template = loader.get_template('TestBench/MainView.html')
context = {
    'testBenchdb': testBenchdb,
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

This is my **model class**

```
class TestBenchDB(models.Model):
Sl_No= models.IntegerField
TestBenchID= models.CharField(max_length=200)
project = models.CharField(max_length=200)
status= models.CharField(max_length=200)
TestPass = models.IntegerField
TestFail=models.IntegerField
FrameworkErrors=models.IntegerField
LastUpdated=models.DateTimeField
```

This is my **template**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon? 
 family=Material+Icons">
 <style>
.blueboxed {
    border: 10px solid #b9fcff;
    background: #b9fcff;
}
    .GreyBoxed{
        border: 10px solid #f2f2f2;
    background: #f2f2f2;

    }
    .WhiteSpace
    {
         border: 5px solid #ffffff;
    background: #ffffff;
    }
    table {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}
    td, th {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
 }
    tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color:rgba(170,236,255,0.86);

 }
th{
    background-color: rgba(8,153,255,0.86)
;
}
tr{
     -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #535353;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #535353;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #535353;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
    .roundbox {

}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="roundbox">
<div class="blueboxed">
<p style="text-align:left;">Dr.PotatoHead
<span style="float:right;"><a href="url">SignOut</a></span>
</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="GreyBoxed">
<p><a href="url">Refresh</a> <a href="url">Add Bench</a> <a 
href="url">StopServers</a></p>
</div>
<br>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Sl.No.</th>
    <th>Test Bench Id</th>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Test Pass</th>
    <th>Test Fail</th>
    <th>Framework Errors</th>
    <th>Last Updated</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
 </tr>

    {% if testBenchdb %}
    {% for tb in testBenchdb %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{  tb.id}}</td>
            <td>{{ tb.TestBenchID }}</td>
            <td>{{tb.project}}</td>
            <td>{{tb.status}}</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>4/20/2018 3:13:56 PM</td>
            <td>
                <button style="font-size:12px"><i class="material- 
          icons">pause</i></button>
                <button style="font-size:12px"><i class="material- 
          icons">error</i></button>
                <button style="font-size:12px"><i class="material- 
          icons">settings_backup_restore</i></button>
                <button style="font-size:12px"><i class="material- 
          icons">help_outline</i></button>
            </td>
         </tr>

    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

  </table>
  {#   <script>#}
  {#    var append_increment = 0;#}
  {#    setInterval(function() {#}
  {#        $.ajax({#}
  {#            type: "GET",#} 
  {#            url: {% url 'get_more_tables' %},  // URL to your view that 
       serves new info#}
  {#            data: {'append_increment': append_increment}#}
  {#        })#}
  {#        .done(function(response) {#}
  {#            $('#_appendHere').append(response);#}
  {#            append_increment += 10;#}
  {#        });#}
  {#    }, 10000)#}
  {#    </script>#}
  {#<script>#}
  {#    var append_increment = 0;#}
  {#    setInterval(function() {#}
  {#        $.ajax({#}
  {#            type: "GET",#}
  {#            url: {% url 'index' %},  // URL to your view that serves new 
  info#}
  {#            data: {'append_increment': append_increment}#}
  {#        })#}
  {#        .done(function(response) {#}
  {#            $('#_appendHere').append(response);#}
  {#            append_increment += 10;#}
  {#        });#}
  {#    }, 10000)#}
  {#</script>#}

  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: So you want to push data from server to the browser whenever there is a change in the data in a database table?

Comment: Yes,For the First time I am able to fetch data ,but later when there is some change in database,I want my table to get updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can achieve this:

1. **Web Sockets**: Web Socket allows you to have a duplex communication between the client and server. And server can also initiate the communication once client connect to the server via a web socket. Web Sockets are supported by almost all modern browser these days.
   For reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plYRxKUow5w
2. **Long polling your server**: In this your client will send a get request to your server. And server will keep the request on a hold and check the database if there are any changes from the version that has been rendered for the client. There could be 3 possibilities here:

If there are no change and hold timeout is not reached; the process will keep holding the request and poll database again after sometime.

If there is a change and hold timeout is not reached; then the process will return the changes to client.

If there is no change and hold timeout is reached; then the process will return indicating that there was no change.

After receiving a response from the server the client will do the get request again. And the whole process will keep repeating itself.

**Word of caution**: Please set the hold timeout appropriately otherwise your client will keep waiting. Set timeout on client as well so that if it does not hear back from the server then it can re initiate the request.

For reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vaIcwhfuweo

Comment: Can we do it with ajax I just have to load table data everytime?

Comment: The second method uses an ajax get request.

Comment: Could you help me out how to work with ajax request?

Comment: Were you able to make progress?

Comment: No still stuck .:(